# Scrolling error in Ubuntu GNOME 16.10

Tags: gnome, mouse, 16.10, ubuntu-gnome, scrolling

I was messing around with Ubuntu GNOME 16.10, when suddenly my mouse scroll wheel started acting up then reversed itself (up became down). It is occurring in multiple applications, including the 'Test Your Settings' part of the mouse config in System Settings. In System Settings I turned natural scrolling on and off, but nothing worked, I tried restarting Ubuntu to see if it would go away, but it didn't. With the same mouse on the host PC on Windows I don't have this issue, it just happens on this Ubuntu installation.

Do you have any ideas as to what I might have done or what went wrong? Or even better how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345858

putting this into the terminal sorted it out

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false